# What does the star symbol means in the binary operation a*b .... Ex: x*y=x+y+xy

Tags: binary-operations

what does the star symbol means in binary operation algebra (logic) 
Does it refer to a certain rule

Comment: Note $1+x*y = (1+x)(1+y)$ so the "*" operation is isomorphic to multiplication.

Comment: The votes to close surprise me. I think this is a reasonable question for someone new to abstract algebra. It's posed clearly and directly.

Comment: Its ok and i think that it is clear enough anyway thanxs ✋

Answer (score 4):

It means the operation defined on the RHS.

For example
$$2*3= 2+ 3+2\times 3=11$$

Comment: I think using the same star for both the defined operation and multiplication is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 3):

No.

In your example $x*y$ is being *defined* to mean the binary operation: $x+y+xy$.  (Presumably so you can solve some problem about such a binary operation.)

In another problem you might be told $x*y$ means something else.  Or in general we can say "Let $*$ be a binary operation" and we won't know anything about what $x*y$ *is*; just that it is some binary operation.

Answer (score 1):

I doesn't refer to a certain rule, it refers to the particular rule defined at the moment.

Answer (score -1):

In binary logic $+$ refers to OR and $\cdot$ refers to AND.

You could also use alternate notation $x\lor y\lor(x\land y)$ but it is equivalent to simple $x\lor y$ or $x+y$ in the origninal notation.

Assuming it is really a logical operation, I do not see the purpose of defining $*$ if it is the same thing as $+$ or maybe this is th epurpose of the exercise to show they are the same rules.

Anyway, I sometimes saw $*$ being used for NAND i.e. $\lnot(x\land y)$ or $(xy)'$ in both notations.

But this is not the case here, are you certain about the definition of $x*y$ ?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_gate

Comment: I'm very surprised by the downvote ? Could you explain please.